# optimization problem: Find Phase of input for minimized max output

Tags: optimization, operating-systems

Let the $\textbf{bold characters}$ represent the vectors/matrices.All the vectors/matrices/scalars only refer to real numbers.

In a continuous LTI system.

$\frac{d\mathbf{T}(t)}{dt}=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{T}(t)+\mathbf{B}$

in which $\mathbf{T}=[T_i]_{N\times 1}$, $\mathbf{B}=[B_i]_{N\times 1}$ and $\mathbf{A}=[A_{i,j}]_{N\times N}$. $\mathbf{A}$ is a given constant matrix. $\mathbf{T}(t)$ are real valued function of $t$. All $\mathbf{T}(t)$, $\mathbf{B}$ and $\mathbf{A}$ only contain real numbers.$t>0$.

$B_i$ is different square-pulse input, that $B_i(x_i)=u(x_i)-u(x_i-K_i)$, where $K_i$ is the given pulse width and $K_i>0$.
$u(t)$ is a continuous unit-step function as $u(t)=1$ when $t\geq 0$; $u(t)=0$, otherwise.

How can we find a phase $\mathbf{X}=[x_i]_{N\times 1}$ such that the output $\max(\mathbf{T}(t))$ can be minimized?

---

So far, my idea is to use Sinusoidal to approximate the square inputs signal, then calculate their phase. Then, use superposition method. However, it still need to use numerical method to check the $t_i$ for different $B_i$. Is there any simpler way? Any paper talk about this? Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like signal processing, so perhaps more appropriate in http://electronics.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was cross-posted on DSP.SE.

Comment: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/37965/5874.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).